# Render view in specific language

Tags: 7, views, theming, i18n-l10n

How to render view in specific language?

```
$view = views_get_view("commerce_line_items_custom");
////Pass arguments
$view->set_arguments(array($data['commerce-order']->order_id));
$view->hide_admin_links = TRUE;
////Generate content
$content =  $view->execute_display('block');
```

I tried following overide, but it did nothing:

```
$view->set_display('block');
$view->display_handler->options['field_language'] = 'fr';
$view->display_handler->display->display_options['field_language'] = 'fr';
$view->display_handler->default_display->options['field_language'] = 'fr';
$view->display_handler->set_option('field_language', 'fr');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following solution:

```
      // Replace language by language of user for correct rendering of view.
      $language_list =  language_list();
      $language_org = $language;
      $language = $language_list[$lang];
      ////Get view
      $view = views_get_view("commerce_line_items_custom");
      ////Pass arguments
      $view->set_arguments(array($data['commerce-order']->order_id));
      $view->hide_admin_links = TRUE;
      ////Generate content
      $content =  $view->execute_display('block');
      $replacements[$original] = $content['content'];
      // Restore language
      $language = $language_org;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this.

```
function yourmodule_views_pre_render(&$views) {
  if ($views->name == 'yourviewname') { //yourviewname is the machine name of the view
    $_SESSION['language'] = fr;
  }
}
```